# Angular Dependency Injection - Specifying a common Parent Injector

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a **BaseCoponent** in which I statically inject a ***NotificationService***:

*base.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'base-component.component.html'
})
export class BaseComponent extends Component implements OnInit {
    protected baseNotificationService: NotificationService;

    static baseInjector: Injector = Injector.create({
        providers: [{
            provide: NotificationService, deps: []
        }]
    });

    constructor(x: number = 0) {
        super(null);

        this.baseNotificationService = BaseComponent.baseInjector.get(NotificationService);
    }
}
```

Another component **MessageDialogComponent** which extends **BaseComponent** but also injects ***NotificationService*** via its constructor:

*message-dialog.component.ts*

```
export class MessageDialogComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {
        super(null);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Here is the problem
        console.log(this.baseNotificationService == this.notificationService); // prints false
    }
}
```

Here's the module:

*core.module.ts*

```
export class CoreModule {
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
    }

    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [
                ...
                NotificationService,
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Problem**:

Inside components, instances of *NotificationService* are different. See the line `this.baseNotificationService == this.notificationService` above in *message-dialog.component.ts*.

Is there a way to make them refer the same instance? I suspect there might be a way that I could specify a `prentInjector` while statically injecting services in BaseComponent, so that when child components inject those services via constructor, they refer the same singleton.

I know I could use `this.baseNotificationServie` inside child components, but it would require a lot of code modification in project.

Comment: why do you statically inject a NotificationService?  If you injects NotificationService via BaseComponent's  constructor you should have the same instance of NotificationService in both of your components.

Comment: If I inject a service in **BaseComponent**'s constructor, each child component then must inject that service in its constructor and provide it to Base via `super`. Not a desireable behavior.